# SFMC JOBID Creation for each Transactional Messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, transactional-messaging-api

How the JOBID creates for each Transactional Messaging in SFMC? Is it like for each API hit creates a jobid or it creates JOBID for a batch in intervals?

Answer (score 1):

The JobID for Transactional Messaging in SFMC is similar to that of Triggered Sends in that each time you 'Publish' (PATCH via API) your Message, a unique JobID is created.

This is then used for all messages sent for that Transactional message until you 'Publish' again.

Comment: Thank You @Gortonington